# SOSL Returning incorrect result

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl

We have one Unit Object and it has Description Text Field 255 char.
Unit Object has 50 records with '48" Test Description' As a value in description__c field.

Now We have SOSL Query as below,

```
    String keyword = '48"';
   
    String findRecordsByKeywordQuery = 'FIND:keyword IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Unit__c (Id where Model__c =\'50\')';
    
    system.debug(search.query(findRecordsByKeywordQuery)[0].size());

-- Output - 6 Records
```

Now if we search with below keyword

```
 String keyword = '48" Test';
       
        String findRecordsByKeywordQuery = 'FIND:keyword IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Unit__c (Id where Model__c =\'50\')';
        
        system.debug(search.query(findRecordsByKeywordQuery)[0].size());

-- Output - 50 Records
```

Can someone help me to understand why we are getting different result with 48" VS 48" Test?

Comment: SOSL performs keyword token searching, where the given search query (here in your "keyword" variable) is split into separate tokens at the space character, and looks for each token in all SOSL indexed fields separately. It should also be noted that SOSL runs using an index and it takes time to generate such an index. Are you sure you waited long enough for the indexing to complete before running both your queries? If you repeat the first one again, is it still 6 records?

Comment: @PhilW Yes, I think it's not related to indexing. We have been seeing same behaviors since last 14 days.

Comment: Are you seeing these issues with literally those example search query strings? SOSL supports the "AND" and "OR" keywords between tokens and has some specific behaviours (dropping these operators) when the search query string gets long.